# How to use gradle (not wrapper) in androiddeployqt/QtCreator?

Tags: android, gradle, qt-creator

By default androiddeployqt tool uses gradle-wrapper. But how can one toggle to use already installed gradle, not the wrapper? At quick look I see no relevant options in androiddeployqt. Maybe, some options possible in android-project-deployment-settings.json? I'm using Qt 5.15.

Thanks in advance.